# Pages should have priority when using add_rewrite_rule

Tags: functions, pages, rewrite-rules

I'm using the following code to have dynamic pages

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^prefix-(.*)', 'foo/bar/index.php?page=$matces[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

This catches `/prefix-*` pages and serves my `index.php` file. For example: `/prefix-foo` serves `foo/bar/index.php?page=foo`.

If I add a new page with the url `/prefix-foo`, I want it to have priority (to serve the content from the database, not from my PHP file).

How can I do that without changing the regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could try to replace:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^prefix-(.*)', 'foo/bar/index.php?page=$matces[1]', 'top' );
```

with

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^prefix-(.*)', 'foo/bar/index.php?page=$matces[1]', 'bottom' );
```

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule):

> '`top`' will
>   take precedence over WordPress's existing rules, where '`bottom`' will
>   check all other rules match first. Default: "`bottom`"

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but this doesn't work, I have just tested. After adding the rule, the page was working (e.g. `/foo`) and then I created a WP page with the same url (`/foo`). After creating the page, the url is still fetching my PHP file. Why?

Comment: Thanks for the status update. The `add_rewrite_rule()` is a wrapper for `WP_Rewrite::add_rule()`. There we see that if these are external rules it uses [`WP_Rewrite::add_external_rule()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/703d5bdc8deb17781e9c6d8f0dd7e2c6b6353885/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1650-L1660) instead that only works for Apache and not e.g. NginX. Note the descriptions [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/703d5bdc8deb17781e9c6d8f0dd7e2c6b6353885/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1490-L1491) where it says: @IonicăBizău

Comment: _"Will add the non_wp_rules property rules to the .htaccess file before the WordPress rewrite rules one."_ There's a `mod_rewrite_rules` filter [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/703d5bdc8deb17781e9c6d8f0dd7e2c6b6353885/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1552-L1559) that gives you the possibility to adjust the generated rules before it's stored in the .htaccess file, but I don't see how it would work to move them after the WordPress rewrite rules. So you should probably use another workaround than the `add_rewrite_rule()` in this case. @IonicăBizău

Comment: I see that you've already got a great workaround by Milo ;-) @IonicăBizău